# MYSQL importing is slow on all sql files

Tags: mysql

I have two databases one is around 127mb and other is 2.5GB. I tried to import those sql files using `mysql.exe -u root {dbname} < {sqlpath.sql}`

But it takes so much time 127mb database took around 2 hours and 2.5 gb database around 2 days. 
I tried it again by adding

```
SET autocommit=0;
SET unique_checks=0;
SET foreign_key_checks=0;
```

to the beginning of my import file and

```
COMMIT;
SET unique_checks=1;
SET foreign_key_checks=1;
```

to the end of my import file but there is no change.
 my tables are `InnoDB` and I am using `MySql 5.7.14`. Any Idea ?

Comment: If each record is imported via a separate insert statement, then it sounds about right.

Comment: @Shadow then how can i solve that ?

Comment: You can't - unless you change the way the data is exported. When you have massive data, then only the structure should be exported as sql statements. The rest should be in plain tabular format that can be loaded via load data infile.

Comment: I can export the data again, how should I export it ?